# Systemd log to file prepend timestamp

Tags: bash, systemd, services, systemctl

I have a systemd service that logs to files:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/my_service
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/my_service/log.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/my_service/err_log.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to prepend the current timestamp to each line as can be achieved in the terminal with the `ts` command from `moreutils` using:

```
/path/to/my_service | /usr/bin/ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
```

I tried:

```
ExecStart=/path/to/my_service | /usr/bin/ts '[%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S]'
```

but the log output still looks the same.

How can I prepend the timestamp to each line in both the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ExecStart parameter](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) does not support full shell functionality. See this description in the [Command lines section](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) of that page:

> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. **Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.**

(my emphasis)

Invoke a wrapper shell to do the work:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/path/to/my_service 2> >(/usr/bin/ts '[%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S]' >&2) | /usr/bin/ts '[%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S]'"
```

Here we're redirecting stderr to a process substitution (which requires bash) that performs the `ts` timestamping and redirects its output to stderr so that systemd's StandardError catches it. The original command's stdout is piped through `ts` and sent on to stdout for systemd's StandardOutput to catch.